# How to submit a form (to php) with JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to do this through jQuery-ajax without reloading the page. But I can't even get the click function to work. The code looks like this..

```
            $("#add").click(function(){
            var selval = $('#cat').val();
            alert('ok');
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"main_end.php",
                data:"categ="+selval,
                success:function(response){
                    $('#results').html("test");

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Would need to see the HTML.

Comment: does the alert('ok') work?

Comment: @Vic it works. I simply cleared the cache/cookies and restarted the browser and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add error tag as shown below and make sure you are not getting any error here :

```
   $("#add").click(function(){
       var selval = $('#cat').val();
       alert('ok');
       $.ajax({
           type:"POST",
                url:"main_end.php",
                data:"categ="+selval,
                success:function(response){
                    $('#results').html("test");
                },
                error : function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { // Add this and make sure you are not getting any error..
                    console.log ('xhr :'+xhr+' textstatus: '+textStatus+' errorThrown :'+errorThrown);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This article will help: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Basically the same thing you are doing, get the form values and submit it into the ajax data.
If that isn't working for you then you probably have some other error, maybe in the HTML or you are running this JS before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: It was a browser problem. Just cleared the history and cookies and restarted. Works now.